# Integration of $\sec(x+2) \tan(x+2)/\sqrt{x+2} $

Tags: calculus

What is $\int\frac{\sec(x+2)\tan(x+2)}{\sqrt{x+2}}dx$?

I tried the $u=\sqrt{x+2}$ but just get $\int 2\sec(u^2)\tan(u^2)du$, which I am stuck on.

Also tried $w=x+2$ which gives a similar problem, $\int\frac{\sec w\tan w}{\sqrt{w}}dw$.

So anyone who can help me with this, please do. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts?

Comment: yes I have but get stuck as well as the only option is $u=\sec(x^2)\tan(x^2)$ and $dx=dv$, so end up with something that doesn't go anywhere. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Well $\sec(x)\tan(x)$ is the derivative of $\sec(x)$ so maybe that can help.

Comment: Both Mathematica and Maple fail with it. Evil omen.